# Simultaneous Equations with coefficients in an arithmetic sequence

Tags: arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

Solve:
$2x+5y=8,
-10x-7y=-4$
or
$x+2y=3,
4x+5y=6$
you will find that they have the same solutions. In fact any two simultaneous equations of the form: $ax+(a+d)y=a+2d, bx+(b+e)y=b+2e$ will have the same solution.

I thought this was interesting and wondered if the result can be generalised. I think in 3d, 3 planes will share a line of solutions.

Comment: In general: simultaneous equations $ax+(a+d)y=fa+gd$, $bx+(b+e)y=fb+ge$ will always have the same solution for any $a, b, d, e$ (except case $a(b+e)=b(a+d)$ when there are many solutions), because $x=f-g$, $y=g$ is always solution.